# WifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress() wrong IP

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I've got two devices - Note 3 (N9005) and G Pad 8.3 (also tested with Nexus 4 instead of the note 3, same results).
When I create a Wifi P2P group when the Note 3 is the group owner, on the G Pad (client) the method `WifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress()` return the right IP.
But when I create a Wifi P2P group when the G Pad is the group owner, on the Note 3 (client) the method return wrong IP address!

here is an ipconfig from the G Pad as group owner with the right ip address:

[image: ipconfig on the tablet while being group owner]

and here is the `ECONNREFUSED` exception on the Note 3 when trying to connect the given ip address:

```
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 7958) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at com.yoavst.wifidirectlib.WifiP2P$5.run(WifiP2P.java:237)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
11-25 21:04:53.264    4817-4986/com.example.wifidirect.app W/System.err﹕ ... 7 more
```

*192.168.49.1 is not 192.168.49.129*

Here are also the code, but I don't think it is the problem:

**Client**

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
                    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                    socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress(), PORT_GET_IP)), 5000);
                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
                    oos.writeObject(HANDSHAKE_STRING);
                    oos.close();
                    os.close();
                    socket.close();
```

**Server**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_GET_IP);
                            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                            Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
                            if (object.getClass().equals(String.class) && object.equals(HANDSHAKE_STRING)) {
                                otherDeviceINetAddress = client.getInetAddress();
                                initClient(client.getInetAddress().toString().substring(1));
                            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrong ip? The group owner's address will always default to 192.168.49.1. According to Android's WifiP2p specs there will always be one group owner in one group at a time. Maybe the group owner is not who you think it is. Are you opening up a  server socket in all of the devices?

Comment: Very strange. Looks like the tablet refuse to be the group owner!
It doesn't mattery from where I do the connect, the tablet is not the group owner :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your last comment, you can't set the device you want as the group owner. What steps have you taken so far? Per the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html), you can try to set the Group Owner when you first try to connect via the WifiP2pConfig class setting the [groupOwnerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html#groupOwnerIntent) However, this is not 100% reliable and the system may end up deciding who the group owner will be, specially if you had already established a connection in the past and the group information has been persisted.